# Python Sqlite: how to select non-existing records(rows) based on a column?

Tags: python, sqlite

Hope everyone's doing well.

Database:

```
Value               Date
---------------------------------
3000             2019-12-15
6000             2019-12-17
```

What I hope to return:

> "Data:3000 on 2019-12-15"

> "NO data on 2019-12-16" (non-existing column based on Date)

> "Data:6000 on 2019-12-17"

I don't know how to filter non-existing records(rows) based on a column.

Possible boilerplate code:

```
db = sqlite3.connect("Database1.db")
cursor = db.cursor()
cursor.execute("""
SELECT * FROM Table1
WHERE Date >= "2019-12-15" and Date <= "2019-12-17"
""")
entry = cursor.fetchall()
for i in entry:
    if i is None:
        print("No entry found:", i)
    else:
        print("Entry found")
db.close()
```

Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The general way you might handle this problem uses something called a *calendar* table, which is just a table containing all dates you want to see in your report.  Consider the following query:

```
SELECT
    d.dt,
    t.Value
FROM
(
    SELECT '2019-12-15' AS dt UNION ALL
    SELECT '2019-12-16' UNION ALL
    SELECT '2019-12-17'
) d
LEFT JOIN yourTable t
    ON d.dt = t.Date
ORDER BY
    d.dt;
```

In practice, if you had a long term need to do this and/or had a large number of dates to cover, you might setup a bona-fide calendar table in your SQLite database for this purpose.  The above query is only intended to be a proof-of-concept.

Comment: Thank you for taking your time to help me. I really appreciate it! So after struggling for another few hours, here's what I've managed to. As you suggested, I've created a bona-fide calendar table with dates from 2019-12-01 to 2020-12-01. Database name: CalendarDates; Column name = Date
```
SELECT * FROM CalendarDates
LEFT JOIN Table1
ON Table1.Date = CalendarDates.Date
```
I understand what you're saying, but I still don't quite know how to query non-existing records. As you probably can tell, I'm very new to SQL (or programming in general), so please as ELI5 as possible. Thanks again!

Comment: And...do you have a question?

Comment: The whole point of the calendar table is that it generates the missing records.

Comment: ```SELECT * FROM Table1
LEFT JOIN CalendarDates
ON Table1.Date = CalendarDates.Date
WHERE Table1.Date DOES NOT EXIST
```
How would I tanslate this concept into valid SQL statement? Thank you again!

Comment: You don't need the `WHERE` clause, at least not the restriction you put there.  The left join by default will include every date in your calendar table.

Comment: Thank you for sticking with me. I appreciate it. But I do need a WHERE clause to select particular data in this week: 
```
WHERE Table1.Activity = "Running" AND Table1.Date >= date('now', 'weekday 0', '-6 day') and Table1.Date < date('now', 'weekday 1')
```
And this returns no result. Could you enlighten me a bit more? Thanks!